# PHP regex for specific phone number format

Tags: php, regex

im trying to validate phone number in php. The requirements are (0d)dddddddd or 0d dddddddd where d is 0-9. This is what I have right now

```
if(!preg_match("/^0[0-9]{9}$/", $phone))
{
//wrong format
}
```

I have tried several similar questions, but still cant understand regex very well.
Can anyone help me fix the regex?

Comment: can you provide some examples of valid numbers

Comment: Sure. Something like (05)12345678 or 05 12345678

Comment: "Something like" is not good enough when talking about regular expressions. You have to be as exact as you possibly can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
if(!preg_match("~^(?:0\d\s|\(0\d\))\d{8}$~", $phone))
{
//wrong format
}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mW4fM3/1)

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  0                        '0'
  \d                       digits (0-9)
  \s                       whitespace 
 |                        OR
  \(                       '('
  0                        '0'
  \d                       digits (0-9)
  \)                       ')'
)                        end of grouping
\d{8}                    digits (0-9) (8 times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helps someone who is still learning like me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\(0\d\)|0\d\s)\d{8}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/8

Answer (score 0):

```
^((\(0\d\))|(0\d ))\d{8}$
```

matches

```
(05)12345678
05 12345678
```

see the example http://regex101.com/r/zN4jE4/1

```
if(!preg_match("/^((\(0\d\))|(0\d ))\d{8}$/", $phone))
{
//wrong format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(!preg_match("^(?:\(0\d\)|0\d\s)\d{8}$", $phone))
{
//wrong format
}
```